# CodeIgniter - constructors in models

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, oop

So here is my controller:

```
class Search extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('search_model');
        $this->search_model->search_result = $_POST;
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $data['results'] = $this->search_model->get_results();
        $this->load->view('search_results', $data);
    }
```

And here is my model:

```
class Search_model extends CI_Model {

    protected $search_query;

    function __construct($search_query)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->search_query = $search_query;
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work. What I want to do is pass the posted form ($_POST) to my model, then do stuff with it. But it seems messy to pass $_POST to each method of my model. My plan is to extract the variables sent with $_POST and construct these as properties such as $website_url, $text_query etc..., then call these in methods with $this->website_url;

I'm relatively new to CodeIgniter so just getting to grips with the basics

Comment: Protected... does that word seem obvious to only me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for your special purpose you can try this code

Controller:

```
class Search extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('search_model');
    $this->init();
}

private function init()
{
    $this->search_model->init( $this->input->post() );
}

public function index()
{

    $data['results'] = $this->search_model->get_results();
    $this->load->view('search_results', $data);
}
```

model:

```
class Search_model extends CI_Model {

protected $search_query;

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

public function init( $search_query )
{
   $this->search_query = $search_query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have `protected $search_query;` which you can't access it from your controller.
You either have to change it to `public` or create getter and setter for it. or just getter depending on your domain/business logic.

And it should have been obvious as you should get an error saying

> Fatal error: Cannot access protected property in file some/path/to/file!

Answer (score -1):

Don't put the 'search query' in your model constructor.

Controller:

```
class Search extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('search_model');
}

public function index()
{
    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST')
    {
        // you should probably validate/clean the post data instead
        // of sending it straight to the model
        $results = $this->search_model->get_where($_POST);
    }
    else
    {
        // if it's not a post, you probably need something...
        // either here, or somewhere in your view to handle empty data
        $results = array();
    }

    $data['results'] = $results
    $this->load->view('search_results', $data);
}
```

Your Model:

```
class Search_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database(); // <--- you may want to autoload 'database' library
}

function get_where($where)
{
     $this->db->where($where);
     // add select, order, joins, etc here
     return $this->db->get('mytable'); // whatever your table name is
}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage using $_POST.  And, "$this->load->database();" may be needed depending on the how user set up framework's configuration.

Comment: 1. I have it in a comment to clean POST data, 2. $_POST is the same as `$this->input->post()` in CodeIgniter (globals are cleaned in System/Input library)...but you're right about `load->database()`, it is needed if you aren't autoloading it (I've never worked on a project that didn't use the DB everywhere, but I'm sure it makes sense on smaller sites).